# Manipulating CRON expressions

Tags: java, c++, time, cron

I am trying to utilize cron in one of my projects where I need some flag to be enabled for a particular period and disable it again. The flag could be in a file or in a shared memory.

I am fairly new to cron but I got the idea that we can schedule to start a cmd at any particular time. So if I want to set a flag I can write a program to read the file or attach to shared memory update the flag and close those and exit. But the problem is after say X minutes the flag should be disabled again.

I thought having two cron jobs to do the work would help. We can fire the same cmd with different arguments and I can swap the flag accordingly. Is this a good approach?

If its so; I am stuck at manipulating given cron expression. If I have only the exp which swaps the flag at a (periodic)start time and a duration for which the flag needs to be active; is there a way to effectively add the duration (anything in days/hours/minutes) to existing cron exp and create a new exp? Or do I need to write entire logic of adding and adjusting fields accordingly to achieve it?

I have components written in Java and C++ which has access to this cron exp. So doing it in either language is fine for me. Right now I am trying in C++.

Comment: If you disable the command after some time - let's say 10 minutes, this would mean you want to start the program only once in the next 10 minutes? Why then use a cron job? Why don't you either invoke the command directly (maybe in a thread in the background) or use `at`, where you can say `at now + 5 minutes`?

Comment: That command can be scheduled peridically too. Like start every first day of every week at 3am and stop at 5am. Something like that.

Comment: So is it a server process that you need to stop it? Other programs normally run and end when they're finished. If so, you would need two entries, one for starting, one for stopping.

Comment: Exactly my statement in question! The problem now is; how can I form the second entry given the first cron exp and the duration after which i have to stop. it seems simple for simple expressions; but might get complex for complex cron

Comment: Well - give specific examples. I don't see what is getting complicated. If you cross a date border, yes. If you want to start at every 28 of a month, 23:50 and need to run it 4h - now what about Feb., what about leap years? Or daylight saving times. Else, it should be pretty trivial, shouldn't it?

Comment: Exactly; If its trivial its write. But the incoming expressions is open to anything so the possibilities of cases you mentioned are there. I need to handle each and everything very carefully if I want to do that. So was just wondering whether there is another way or maybe I am just going in wrong direction.

Comment: Well, you could start a wrapper script, capture the PID of a program which you start in the background, and kill that by PID after some time. But if the program you start starts another process, this ohter one might run independently. I don't see an automatic catch-all solution.

Comment: yeah; I might prolly write the entire logic on my own or use a different approach. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classic crontab line

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   echo crontabfoo > /dev/null
```

flagged inactive crontab line:

```
 # */5  *   *   *   *   echo crontabfoo > /dev/null
```

Yes, just an ordinary comment. If it runs once every 5 Minutes, and you comment it out after 6 minutes, it still has a short chance to run twice, so perhaps you like to specify a concrete time in the near future.

Comment: I want to achieve a periodic flag enable/disable in my program. I am trying to utilize CRON for it. Say I have a process running continuously; I want a flag inside my process to be true only during 3AM-5AM every first day of a week for all weeks.

Comment: I found a way to indicate about the flag using another notifying process (which seems to be already there in our implementation)